# how to change date at a specific time

Tags: c#

I m very new to C# and have some issue. I've a project where I need to change the date when School starts at 0700 am only not at 1200 am. I tried something like this but doesn't work

```
System.TimeSpan timeDiff = TimeSpan.FromHours(.292);
DateTime presentDate = (Convert.ToDateTime(sysDateTime)).Subtract(timeDiff);
```

I used this way in VB6 where I just substract .292 from current dateTime to change the date at 0700 am instead of 1200 am but dont know how do I achieve the same in C#.

Comment: some more information ... the "sysDateTime" is the SYSDATE from Oracle which changed to a new date at 1200 am but what I want to have is to change everyday only at 0700 am ...

Comment: 0.292 seems not the correct value instead use something like this `System.TimeSpan timeDiff = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
DateTime d = (Convert.ToDateTime(sysDateTime)).Subtract(new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0));
```